# Call an another method right after calling model class constructor (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to set my Order Object's total amount with the total of selected products (order_items) prices at that time. I want to call an another method right after Order constructor, So that the amount won't change when change in Product price

My Order Class is:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.
    order_items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem, related_name="order_items")
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    .........
```

My OrderItem Class is:

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    ........
```

My Product Class is:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default=None)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    product_type = models.ForeignKey(ProductType, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT,default = None, null=True, blank=True)
    ......
```

Comment: You can use django signals. Your signals can be triggered before or after saving the model to database. Will that work?

Comment: @KshitijSaxena May be it could work, but i don't want to use extra code outside model class

Comment: You can override `save` method in your model and add your code after super call.